# deleting objects if string of object matches string in a separate array

Tags: arrays, swift, string

I have an nsobject class with four strings

```
class Post: NSObject {
    var author: String!
    var postID: String!
    var pathToImage: String!
    var userID: String!
}
```

I also have a separate class viewcontroller which has a function grabbing posts from firebase. I have an array called `posts = [Post]()`, which is filled by a seperate function going through firebase and grabbing data for each photo. I also have an array called `removeArray` which is array of strings, which the string is the postID of certain posts. Now this is my problem, I am trying to loop through `removeArray`, check if the each in `removeArray` = to the each in `posts.postID` and check if they are equal. Then either I delete that each in `posts.postID` post, or I create a new array that is posts - posts with postID's in `removeArray`. Here is my code now that does not work, it just keeps posts as is.

```
if posts != nil {
    if var array = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "removeArray") as? [String]  {
        for each in posts {
            for one in array {
                if one == each.postID {
                    new.append(each)
                }
            }
        }

        return self.posts.count
    }
}
```

So if you have any idea how to take a string in an array, check if that string if eqaul to a string in an array of `objects.postID`, and remove that object from the array if it is equal. I have tried to research a way to filter it, but so far nothing. Please give me some feedback. Thanks
My problem = [http://imgur.com/a/m5CiY](https://imgur.com/a/m5CiY)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var posts = [p1,p2,p3,p4,p5]
let array = ["aaa","bbb"]
var new:Array<Post> = []

for each in posts {
    for one in array {
        if one == each.postID {
            new.append(each)
        }
    }
}

print("This objects should be remvoed:  \(new)")
posts = Array(Set(posts).subtracting(new))
print("After removing matching objects: \(posts)")
```

Comment: posts is not an array of strings, rather its an array of NSObjects, as shown in the picture above, class Post. var posts = [Post]()

Comment: ok heres the problem, you are really close, this is where I got, but remember Post is an object right and in each object there are 4 strings = author, postID, pathToImage and userID. At new.append(each) I cannot append a Post to an array of strings. http://imgur.com/a/m5CiY

Comment: @RandyWindin, please check now.

Comment: @RandyWindin, no problem, please add your knowledge with the community when you have something to share.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `reduce(_:_:)`!

```
class Country {

    var name: String!

    init(name: String) {

        self.name = name
    }
}

let countries = [Country(name: "Norway"), Country(name: "Sweden"), Country(name: "Denmark"), Country(name: "Finland"), Country(name: "Iceland")]

let scandinavianCountries = ["Norway", "Sweden", "Denmark"]

// Store the objects you are removing here
var nonScandinavianCountries: [Country]?

let scandinavia = countries.reduce([Country](), {
    result, country in

    // Assign result to a temporary variable since result is immutable
    var temp = result

    // This if condition works as a filter between the countries array and the result of the reduce function.
    if scandinavianCountries.contains(country.name) {

        temp.append(country)
    } else {

        if nonScandinavianCountries == nil {
            // We've reached a point where we need to allocate memory for the nonScandinavianContries array. Instantiate it before we append to it!
            nonScandinavianCountries = []
        }

        nonScandinavianCountries!.append(country)
    }

    return temp
})

scandinavia.count // 3

nonScandinavianCountries?.count // 2
```

Resouces:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/2298686-reduce